# How to Use String Array All Operator in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

My query is as follows:

```
string[] keys = txtSearch.Text.Split(' ');

var query = (from m in db.Messages
             join r in db.Recievers on m.Id equals r.Message_Id
             where (keys.All(k => (m.MessageText + m.Comments.Select(cmt => cmt.CommentText).ToString()).Contains(k)))
             select m.Id).Distinct();
```

I get the following error:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query
>   operators except the Contains() operator.

Comment: seems you cant use local source string[] keys with db source as in where clause u are using local source. Translate with linq as select * from local_source and try

Comment: @Prathyush, how can I solve it?

Comment: Side question: what do you expect to get from `Select(cmt => cmt.CommentText).ToString()`?

Comment: @IvanStoev, I expect all comments to be concatenated together.

Comment: If you are expecting concated value then your query is not correct as Greg also suggested the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your query can't be translated to SQL (or at least the provider is not programmed to do so).  If fact  I don't know how that would query would look in SQL: "Give me all messages where all of these key words are contained in the text or comments"

My first thought is to to multiple requests, one for each key value:

```
List<int> allIDs = new List<int>();
foreach(string key in keys)
{
    var query = (from m in db.Messages
                 join r in db.Recievers on m.Id equals r.Message_Id
                 where m.MessageText.Contains(key) || m.Comments.Any(cmt => cmt.CommentText.Contains(key)
                 select m.Id).Distinct();
    allIds.AddRange(query);
}
```

but you may even need to search for messages and comments in separate queries.

obviously you'd *prefer* to do it in one query, but I don't see how that can be done in SQL without using cursors anyways.  If you can come up with a SQL statement that gives you the right results, then it may be easier to just call that SQL statement directly rather than trying to come up with a Linq statement that is compiled to equivalent SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `Array.Contains()` in linq to SQL queries when using **local collections.**

You need to change your query based on this rule.

Answer (score 0):

The `All` operator returns a boolean, it also determines if *all* elements satisfy a condition.  As you're enumerating, as soon as a condition isn't met, the enumeration stops and returns a true or false.

I believe you're expecting a `Where` functionality, return all the specified elements that satisfy a match on your search.

I don't believe you're utilizing the query correctly.